# Bad value for range

Tags: ruby, variables, loops, range

When I run the following code:

```
def db(y)
  return self % y == 0
end

puts "To number:"
n = gets.chomp

for i in 1..n
  if i.db(3)
    puts "Fizz!"
    if i.db(5)
      puts "FIZZBUZZ!"
    end
  elsif i.db(5)
    puts "Buzz!"
  else
    puts i
  end
end
```

I get a "bad value for range" error. Why does this happen how do I fix it? Normal ranges that use variables for some values work perfectly including for loops, why does *this* not work?

Note: I want the `for` loop to stay as a `for` loop.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just do as below :

```
n = gets.chomp.to_i
```

`gets.chomp` will give you `String` instance. You need to make it as `Fixnum`. Otherwise `1.."4"` for e.g is not a valid range. so error `"bad value for range" error.` [`String#to_i`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-to_i) is your friend.

```
2.0.0p0 :001 > 1.."2"
ArgumentError: bad value for range
    from (irb):1
    from /home/kirti/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
2.0.0p0 :002 > 1..2
 => 1..2 
2.0.0p0 :003 >
```

Comment: [`chomp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-chomp) is superfluous in this case - [`String#to_i`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-to_i) ignores extraneous characters.

Answer (score 7):

[`gets`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) returns String.

You need to convert it to `Fixnum` using [`String#to_i`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-to_i).

---

Replace the following line:

```
n = gets.chomp
```

With:

```
n = gets.chomp.to_i
```